# Two way data binding in angular not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement two way data binding in angular components. Currently its in a parent child mode.

> parent.component.html

```
<child [(title)]="title"></child>
<span style="color: red">This is parent component {{title}}</span>
```

> parent.component.ts

```
title = 'app';
```

> child.component.html

```
<span style="color: blue">This is child component {{title}}</span>
```

> child.component.ts

```
@Input() title: any;
  @Output() pushTitle = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'new title';
    this.pushTitle.emit(this.title);
  }
```

The title should implement on the parent component as well, when I change it from the child. Also, I am not sure why the parent code keeps going in a loop for no reason. I have added text in html just to test if its updated in both the components, but its updating only in the child, and not in the parent. I am coming from the angularjs background, and two way data binding worked seamlessly in it. I am just confused what I am doing wrong(I know its a noob question).

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xttmxg

Comment: Simple way is update from `@Output() pushTitle = new EventEmitter();` to `@Output() titleChange = new EventEmitter();`

Answer (score 2):

There is another way that you can achive the same.

```
@Input() title: any;
@Output() titleChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

changeValue() {
  this.title= !title;
  this.titleChange.emit(this.title);
}
```

Have a look at Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---) about two way binding

Comment: This makes no sense. You will get an error `title is not defined`.

Comment: let me create a stackblitz :)

Comment: @ritaj please have a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way

Comment: Please re-read your answer given. It uses undefined variable. Other than that, yes, that definitely works. Nice work!

Comment: @RukshanDangalla, the stackblitz code is fantastic! I just have one question, can't I just use [(fontSizePx)]="fontSizePx", and assign the input variable as fontSizePx? instead of using size?

Comment: @Aijaz Actually you can. It's about naming conventions. You can change the names as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Two way data binding only works for template - component interaction.

If you want to send title change to parent component, you should do something like this:

Parent template and component:

```
<child [title]="title" (pushTitle)="onTitleChange(value)"></child>
<span style="color: red">This is parent component {{title}}</span>

onTitleChange(value) {
    this.title = value;
}
```

Followup question:

Template:

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="inputModel">
```

Component:

```
inputModel: string;
```

Now, every time you type something into input field you will see changes in component model, OR when change inputModel value programmatically, you will see the change in HTML input.

Comment: Thanks. In what scenario will I be able to use [(title)] then?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: if @ritaj answer satisfies you, you should mark his answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are somehow creating an infinite update cycle using the 2-way-binding. This leads to the infinite loop and eventual stack overflow you noticed.

---

To fix this, preferably, you want to add some logic to the `titleChange` event (this is the *banana*-part of the *banana-in-a-box* syntax, i.e. the part in parens in `[(title)]` which is getting automatically translated into an event emitter named `titleChange`).
For example, you might want to skip updating the `title` property of the parent component if its equal to the update emitted by the child component.

This means you should split up `[(title)]` into `(titleChange)="titleChange($event)"` and `[title]="title"`. The first part lets you pass the updated title as `$event` and then process it in a function `titleChanged` (name is arbitrary in this case). The second part has the effect that the child component receives updates of the parent component's `title` property.

Another common pattern is to make `title` private (commonly with a prefixed underscore, e.g. `_title`) and then add a getter `get title() { return this._title;}` so that you can (1) encapsulate this property and (2) add some processing. 
In your case this is not needed, but it doesn't hurt either. ;-)

---

Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mDohzD5MgYqVGhswtDHc?p=preview) containing these changes.